# what does the same_payer mean in eosio contract?

Tags: smart-contract

```
 user_stakes.modify(sk,same_payer,[&](auto &s){
```

The variable same_payer confused me sometime, so, what does the same_payer mean in eosio contract ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means whomever paid for the RAM originally is still going to be paying for the RAM in the table after this modification. If modification of data consumes more RAM compared to original usage, setting `same_payer` requires authorization of original ram payer. (Or, you can modify data without original payer's authorization, if ram usage is kept same or decreased.)

Comment: Does this mean that we could replace same_payer with to or st.issuer in https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/master/contracts/eosio.token/src/eosio.token.cpp#L46 ?

Comment: You can replace it with any account name you like. But only if you gave the authority of that account for the current transaction